# When I run this program, it does not take the second user input and automatically makes First_User_Input == Second_User_Input

Tags: python

```
from random import randint

board = []

for x in range(0, 5):
  board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
  for row in board:
    print " ".join(row)

print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
  return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
  return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)

ship_col = random_col(board)

print ship_row

print ship_col

guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col: "))

guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row: "))

if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:

  print "Congratulations! You sank my battleship!"   

else:
  if guess_row not in range(5) or \
    guess_col not in range(5):

    print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."

  elif (board[guess_row][guess_col] == 'X'):

    print "You guessed that one already."

  else:
    print "You missed my battleship!"

    board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"

  print_board(board)
```

Comment: What’s not working in this code?  Is there a specific error you’re hitting?  Can you reduce this to a [mcve]?

Comment: guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col: "))
guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row: "))     The user input of guess_row is not working. It only takes one of the inputs.